# Couldn't resolve dependencies with sbt-coursier

Tags: dependencies, sbt, sbt-plugin

I'm using sbt-coursier plugin for resolve the dependencies of my project and my problem is when I'm trying to add a project reference like this

lazy val some-lib =
ProjectRef(uri("ssh://git@github.com/aaa/project.git#sdaf"), "lib")

It doesn't resolve the dependency. I don't know if I need to set another configuration for that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/coursier/coursier/issues/639 - is still unsolved :-(